# Calling web service to web service; Architecture View

Tags: web-services, wcf, architecture, software-design, distributed-transactions

An interesting situation has came today as in the past too.

I have two web services. The transaction will be over after those two has done their own jobs. For this discussion I will name these web services as:

1. RLService
2. NavService

**I cannot combine both services because the service 2 is owned by 3rd party. This 3rd party web service provides me a webmethod that read the xml file stored in that machine, where web service is, and process.**

I have two options:

1. Client to Service**(S)**

   - Client call my web service, RLService, with xml data.
   - RLService store xml data to xml file and return the xml file path
   - Client call Navision web service, NAVService, with xml file path
   - NAVService return the result as xml path.
   - Client call my web service, RLService, with xml file path, which returns back with an Object to proceed further.

State Diagram:

[image: State Diagram]

2. Service to Services

   - Client call my web service, RLService, with xml data.
   - RLService store xml data to xml file
   - RLService call Navision web service, NAVService, with xml file path
   - NAVService return the result as xml path.
   - RLService, processed returned xml and convert to an Object to proceed further.
   - Client receive a class Result object.

   State Diagram:

   [image: State Diagram]

Here is how the physical architecture looks like:

[image: Physical Architecture]

I have followed both ways, but what is the right approach and why?

Of course, I know that the second solution is good. But what about patterns and best practices.

Comment: PS: 1) "RLService store xml data to xml file".  Q: Why?  Why not just forward it directly to the web service (without writing unnecessary files)?  2) RLService, processed returned xml and convert to an Object to proceed further.  Q: Why?  Why can't the client interpret the XML?  Or JSON?  If you convert it to an "object", it's still going to have to be serialized before you transmit it, then deserialized at the client?  Why not send the data directly, and just have the client deserialize it (once)?

Comment: @FoggyDay 1. NAVService webservice only expose the webmethod with file path to process and I don't own the code of this web service. 

2. Because RLService hosted on the same as server as NAVService and RLService can only access the stored result file attached here with. Client is physically located somewhere else.

The only reason why I don't want client to serialize or deserialize is because I want all clients to get the same object and I don't think itis a good idea to send raw Xml that later will be de serialize by each client (manually).

Comment: @FoggyDay to make things bit clearer, I own RLService code, but I don't NAVService. The only reason why I end up making RLService because I don't put adapter against NAVService and expose the way I want it. So It is like an Adapter pattern where RLService is taking my request to do the job the way NAVService wants.

Comment: Like I said below, "Option 2" appears to be better.  For the simple reason that it appears to minimize the number of network messages going back and forth.  IMHO...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: Which approach is better?

A: The fewer round trips, the better.

A: The more you can do in one call (without making another, separate call), the better.

In other words (all things being equal), it looks like your second design is a *LOT* better than the first alternative.

IMHO...

Comment: Question was to know more towards patterns and since both services are hosted within same IIS I could not buy that it will boost the performance. Nevertheless, I appreciate your active participation.

Answer (score 0):

If you put this logic in your service, obviously it decouples the client application from the needed workflow and makes sure the application/business logic is in your business service. In fact, it would be better to keep your client as thin as possible. So solution two would be the preferred solution (for me). You can still decide to make it an asynchronous operation, of course, that depends on your use case.

As a result, any change in logic only impacts your service, not the clients.